# How to group customer spending into three ranges Low, Medium, High. What should the values be for each range?

Tags: excel, database, statistics, analytics

I have a large set of data 100,000 records with the dollar value a customer spends at the store. I need to tag each of these customers with a value of Low, Medium, or High but I don't want to guess what those ranges should be. 
Is there any way I can use excel to do analytics on this data to come up with what values the ranges should be

```
Low = $0 - $500 
Medium = $501 - $2000 
High >= $2001
```

Comment: Take the max minus min and divide by 3 to get the bin size?

Comment: or use the standard deviation and see if it greater or less than one or two standard deviations from the mean.